# Rellenar lista con 0

Tags: python

Tengo una tupla con diferentes valores

```
myVals = (21, 19, 29, 33, 33, 35, 42, 72, 52, 78, 127, 90, 150, 100, 83, 63, 60, 49, 32)
```

Y un valor que es mi divisor

```
div = 3
```

Si dividimos la longitud de mi tupla de valores y el divisor es `19/3 = 6.33`. Por lo tanto si yo quisiera un resultado de valor entero, mi lista debería ser de 21 valores (siempre redondeo al alza) y así daría 7.

¿Hay alguna función que rellene mi tupla con ceros? Es decir, en este caso que añadiera dos ceros al final de esta.

```
myVals = (21, 19, 29, 33, 33, 35, 42, 72, 52, 78, 127, 90, 150, 100, 83, 63, 60, 49, 32, 0, 0)
```

Es decir, busco rellenar con ceros mis tuplas (o listas, da igual) para que su longitud sea múltiplo de mi valor de `divisor`.

Se que dispongo de la función `ceil()` de la librería `math`, pero no veo como hacerlo de una manera eficiente.

Yo he hecho lo siguiente y funciona,

```
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32]
div = 3

res = len(myvals) % div

while res != 0:
  myvals.append(0)
  res = len(myvals) % div

print(myvals)
```

Pero pienso que debe haber una manera más sencilla/eficiente para lograr el mismo resultado.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Apunte rápido: Las tuplas son lista inmutables, una vez creada no la puedes modificar. (por lo de que te daba igual listas o tuplas)

Answer (score 3):

Sencillo, pero no necesariamente más eficiente:

```
divisor = 3

ln = len(myVals)
new_elements = (math.ceil(ln/divisor) * divisor) - ln
myVals = myVals + tuple(0 for _ in range(new_elements))
```

Comentarios

- Efectivamente se usa `ceil()` para que el 6.33 sea 7, lo volvemos a multiplicar por el divisor y tenemos la longitud esperada, la diferencia con la real son los nuevos elementos
- Para agregarlos hacemos una comprensión de listas, para generar los 0 y extender la tupla original

Answer (score 3):

Las tuplas son inmutables, por lo que la única solución es crear una nueva tupla.

Aunque no se pueden expandir, se pueden concatenar, asi que la solución sera crear una nueva tupla agregando otra con valores en cero.

Para genera la tupla de valores en cero usamos la función `tuple(iterable)`. El iterable, en este caso, es una lista ceros. La repetición la logramos escribiendo `[0] * resto`

El código

```
def expand(tupla, multiplo):
    if multiplo == 1:
        return tupla
    resto = multiplo - len(tupla) % multiplo
    return tupla + tuple([0] * resto)

test = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

for i in range(1, 10):
    print(i, expand(test, i))
```

produce:

```
1 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
2 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0)
3 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0)
4 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0)
5 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0)
6 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0)
7 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0)
8 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
9 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que planteas no se puede hacer con tuplas, dado que las tuplas en python son inmutables (no así los valores DENTRO de la tupla).

Con la lista, en vez de andar calculando si la división es exacta en cada vuelta podrías hacer algo así:

```
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32]
div = 3
res = len(myvals) / div  # En vez de coger el resto, cogemos el valor entero
for i in range(int((math.ceil(res) - res) * div)):
    myvals.append(0)
```

Lo que hace este for es calcular la diferencia entre el valor redondeado al alza de res
y res, eso nos devolverá un valor 0 o 1 en principio (además está casteado a int)
y luego lo multiplica por el número de ceros que necesita añadir y simplemente añade esa cantidad de '0's dentro del bucle

Answer (score 1):

También puedes hacer un "one-liner" con

```
myvals = [21,19,29,33,33,35,42,72,52,78,127,90,150,100,83,63,60,49,32]
div = 3

while len(myvals) % div != 0: myvals.append(0)

print(myvals)
```

y te ahorras `res`

Quizás no he entendido bien la pregunta pero no veo una forma más sencilla de atacar tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es usando Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

myVals = (21, 19, 29, 33, 33, 35, 42, 72, 52, 78, 127, 90, 150, 100, 83, 63, 60, 49, 32)

div = 3
expected_size = 21

# Todo el trabajo está en estas dos lineas
values = np.ceil( np.array(myVals)/div )
result = np.pad(values, (0, expected_size - len(values)))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Segunda respuesta**

Lo que no me gusta de mi primera respuesta (y de otras que comparten el enfoque), es que demandan un tratamiento especial de los objetos del usuario: hay que preparar la tupla explícitamente.

**Una subclase de tuple**

Mi segunda respuesta es crear una subclase de la clase `tuple`, de tal manera que con solo invocar

```
myTupla = NTupla((1,2,3,4), 5)
```

tenga lo que quiero: una tupla que parece tener cinco elementos aunque sólo almacena cuatro. De ahi en adelante, es una tupla como cualquier otra. Entonces puedo escribir directamente

```
>>>myTupla[3]
4
>>>myTupla[4]
0
```

Lo mejor es que puedo cambiar el múltiplo a posteriori:

```
>>>myTupla.set_multiplo[6]
>>>myTupla[5]
0
```

Para hacer una subclase de `tuple` necesitamos redefinir el método `__new__`.

```
class Ntupla(tuple):

def __new__(cls, tupla, multiplo):
    return super().__new__(cls, tupla)
```

El método `new` recibe la clase como primer argumento, y luego los restantes argumentos pasados en el constructor.

En nuestro caso, el método simplemente llama al método nativo de la clase `tuple`. El parametro `multiplo` simplemente se ignora (lo recibir `__init__`).

Necesitamos también definir `__init__`. Ambos son usados para la creación de los nuevos objetos.

El item de interés en esta historia es el método `__getitem__`, que es invocado cuando se usa indices. Como queremos cambiar el funcionamiento de `myTupla[idx]`, redefiniremos este método así:

- Si el indice es valido en la tupla original, se devuelve l valor original.
- Si el indice corresponde a la cola rellenada con ceros, se devuelve cero.
- En cualquier otro caso (indice inválido), se devuelve None.

Finalmente, necesitamos redefinir el método **len**, para que cualquier consulta sobre el largo de la tupla traiga el largo simulado (con ceros al final), no el largo real.

[Advertencia: este es un código básico demostrativo. No implementa toda la funcionalidad necesaria. Por ejemplo, falta reimplementar `__str__` ...]

**Código**

```
import math

class Ntupla(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, tupla, multiplo):
        return super().__new__(cls, tupla)

    def __init__(self, tupla, multiplo):
        self.largo_real = len(tupla)
        self.largo_simulado = 0
        self.set_multiplo(multiplo)

    def set_multiplo(self, multiplo):
        self.largo_simulado = math.ceil(self.largo_real / multiplo) * multiplo

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        respuesta = None
        if index in range(self.largo_real):
            respuesta = super().__getitem__(index)
        elif index in range(self.largo_real, self.largo_simulado):
            respuesta = 0

        return respuesta

    def __len__(self):
        return self.largo_simulado
```

**Demostración**

Este programa comprueba el correcto acceso a cada elemento de la tupla:

```
myVals = (21, 19, 29, 33, 33, 35, 42, 72, 52, 78, 127, 90, 150, 100, 83, 63, 60, 49, 32, 0, 0)

a = Ntupla(myVals, 1)
for x in range(2, 16):
    a.set_multiplo(x)
    print("Multiplo ", x, "largo=", len(a), end=" (", )
    for i in range(len(a)):
        print(a[i], end=" ")
    print(")")
```

produce

```
Multiplo  2 largo= 22 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  3 largo= 21 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 )
Multiplo  4 largo= 24 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  5 largo= 25 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  6 largo= 24 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  7 largo= 21 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 )
Multiplo  8 largo= 24 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  9 largo= 27 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  10 largo= 30 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  11 largo= 22 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  12 largo= 24 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  13 largo= 26 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  14 largo= 28 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
Multiplo  15 largo= 30 (21 19 29 33 33 35 42 72 52 78 127 90 150 100 83 63 60 49 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
```